# how to clear stdout after CTRL - C in linux c

Tags: c, linux, stdout, sigint

We dont want anything to be printed after user interrupt via `CTRL-C`. We have tried adding `__fpurge` as well `fflush` inside sigInt signal handler, but it is not working.

How can I clear buffered stdout values immediately? I have came across few similar thread but no where i could able to find a working solution .

Few additional info's:
Inside sigInt signal handler even after adding exit(0) , buffer content are getting printed but the processor is killed .

added exit(0) to narrow down the issue , i dont want to kill the processor

I know the above is expected behavior , not sure how to avoid it .

Comment: Have you tried closing the file descriptor?

Comment: `exit()` is not [async-signal-safe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html). You should use `_Exit()` instead. (Also, the GNU C library version does not flush streams at `_Exit()`, while it does at `exit()`, so that fixes the problem, too. Otherwise, you could redirect the underlying descriptors to `/dev/null/` -- `open()` and `dup2()` are async-signal-safe --, so that whatever is flushed, gets flushed to /dev/null instead.)

Comment: And tell which compiler your using, there might possibly be differences...

Comment: @SergeBallesta: The default action for `SIGINT` is to kill the process, that's why you don't get any output. When you install a signal handler for it, the behaviour changes. (I can reproduce OP's behaviour.)

Comment: Brutal way, possibly even a stupid idea: Do all cleanup as far as possible, then `kill(getpid(), SIGKILL);`? (All within the signal handler, of course...)

Comment: @Aconcagua: Actually, even though I just posted a different answer, that's actually the *least* brutal way I can think of. (In that case, it's the kernel that will kill off the process immediately, not the process itself.) I think that's actually a really good suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this edited example -- edited; this one does not exit the process:

```
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L /* For nanosleep() */
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void exit_handler(int signum)
{
    int fd, result;

    /* If the standard streams are connected to a tty,
     * tell the kernel to discard already buffered data.
     * (That is, in kernel buffers. Not C library buffers.)
    */
    if (isatty(STDIN_FILENO))
        tcflush(STDIN_FILENO, TCIOFLUSH);
    if (isatty(STDOUT_FILENO))
        tcflush(STDOUT_FILENO, TCIOFLUSH);
    if (isatty(STDERR_FILENO))
        tcflush(STDERR_FILENO, TCIOFLUSH);

    /* Redirect standard streams to /dev/null,
     * so that nothing further is output.
     * This is a nasty thing to do, and a code analysis program
     * may complain about this; it is suspicious behaviour.
    */
    do {
        fd = open("/dev/null", O_RDWR);
    } while (fd == -1 && errno == EINTR);
    if (fd != -1) {
        if (fd != STDIN_FILENO)
            do {
                result = dup2(fd, STDIN_FILENO);
            } while (result == -1 && (errno == EINTR || errno == EBUSY));
        if (fd != STDOUT_FILENO)
            do {
                result = dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
            } while (result == -1 && (errno == EINTR || errno == EBUSY));
        if (fd != STDERR_FILENO)
            do {
                result = dup2(fd, STDERR_FILENO);
            } while (result == -1 && (errno == EINTR || errno == EBUSY));
        if (fd != STDIN_FILENO && fd != STDOUT_FILENO && fd != STDERR_FILENO)
            close(fd);
    }
}

static int install_exit_handler(const int signum)
{
    struct sigaction act;
    memset(&act, 0, sizeof act);
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    act.sa_handler = exit_handler;
    act.sa_flags = 0;
    if (sigaction(signum, &act, NULL) == -1)
        return errno;
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    if (install_exit_handler(SIGINT)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot install signal handler: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while (1) {
        struct timespec t = { .tv_sec = 0, .tv_nsec = 200000000L };

        printf("Output\n");
        fflush(stdout);

        nanosleep(&t, NULL);
    }

    /* Never reached. */
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When the process receives a `SIGINT` signal, it will first flush whatever is in kernel terminal buffer, then redirect the standard streams to `/dev/null` (i.e., nowhere).

Note that you'll need to kill the process by sending it the TERM or KILL signal (i.e. `killall ./yourprogname` in another terminal).

---

When you are running the verbose process over a remote connection, quite a lot of information may be in flight at all times. Both the local machine and the remote machine running the process will have their socket buffers nearly full, so the [latency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_latency) may be much larger than ordinarily -- I've seen several second latencies in this case even on fast (GbE) local networks.

This means that propagating the signal from the local machine to the remote machine will take a measurable time; in worst cases on the order of seconds. Only then will the remote process stop outputting data. All pending data will still have to be transmitted from the remote machine to the local machine, and that may take quite a long time. (Typically, the bottleneck is the terminal itself; in most cases it is *faster* to minimize the terminal, so that it does not try to render any of the text it receives, only buffers it internally.)

This is why <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> does not, and cannot, stop remote output instantaneously.

In most cases, you'll be using an SSH connection to the remote machine. The protocol does not have a "purge" feature, either, that might help here. Many, myself included, have thought about it -- at least my sausage fingers have accidentally <kbd>tab</kbd>bed to the executable file instead of the similarly named output file, and not only gotten the terminal full of garbage, but the special characters in binary files sometimes set the terminal state (see e.g. [xterm control sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html), [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)) to something unrecoverable (i.e., <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> followed by `reset` <kbd>Enter</kbd> does not reset the terminal back to a working state; if it did, `kill -KILL %- ; fg` would stop the errant command in Bash, and get you your terminal back), and you need to break the connection, which will also terminate all processes started from the same terminal running remotely in the background.

The solution here is to use a terminal multiplexer, like [GNU screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen), which allows you to connect to and disconnect from the remote machine, without interrupting an existing terminal connection. (To put it simply, `screen` is your terminal avatar on the remote machine.)

Comment: wont tcflush flushes the output to the terminal , we dont want to display any old buffered data into the terminal . tcflush is also not helping :(

Comment: @manimuthuma: No, [tcflush()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) discards data that is in the kernel buffers, but not yet read by the process or processed by the terminal. It is only useful for remote terminals, as local terminals tend to read data immediately.  Did you try my above program at all?

Comment: yes i did and its not helping , termianl is still printing unprinted datas .

Comment: @manimuthuma: Are you sure? I modified the example program to not exit the process, and it sure does stop output for me. Does your program use a custom stream to print to the terminal? If it does, that too should be closed.

Comment: if i use a custom stream , then won't it be closed when the processor exit

Comment: @manimuthuma: If your process uses custom streams, they will be flushed when the process exits normally. Does your process create child processes via `fork()`, `system()`, or `popen()`? Your overall situation does not match what you have described in the question; I suspect it may, in fact, be a child process that does the output, and not the process that has that `SIGINT` handler installed.

Comment: @manimuthuma: And when you run my modified example above, does the output stop when you press Ctrl+C?

Comment: i even tried to use (STDOUT_FILENO,TCOOFF); , it stopped only after printing everything till that point .:(

Comment: @manimuthuma: I think I now know where the problem is. Please see the addendum to my answer, after the horizontal line.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that neither Posix nor Linux library declares that `fpurge` nor `__fpurge` to be safe in a signal handler function. As explained by DevSolar, C language itsel does not declare many safe functions for standard library (at least `_Exit`, but Posix explicitely allows `close` and `write`. So, you can always close the underlying file descriptor which should be 1:

```
void handler(int sig) {
    static char msg[] = "Interrupted";
    write(2, msg, sizeof(msg) - 1);  // carefully use stderr here
    close(1);  // foo is displayed if this line is commented out
    _Exit(1);
}
int main() {
    signal(SIGINT, handler);
    printf("bar");
    sleep(15);
    return 0;
}
```

When I type Ctrl-C during the sleep it gives as expected:

```
$ ./foo
^CInterrupted with 2
$
```

The `close` system call should be enough, because as it closes the underlying file descriptor. So even if there are later attemps to flush stdout buffer, they will write on a closed file descriptor as as such have no effect at all. The downside is that stdout has been redirected, the program should store the new value of the underlying file descriptor in a global variable.

Comment: Unfortunately, glibc (used in most Linux distributions, and the OP has tagged Linux for this question) does not implement it. It does have `__fpurge()` with the same semantics (declared in `"stdio_ext.h"`, though).

Comment: @NominalAnimal: Ok, but even `__fpurge` should clear the stream... unless OP writes a message to stdout first...

Comment: You're quite right, it should. I personally don't like it because it's not async-signal safe (which leads to UB if used in a signal handler), but as I wrote in my answer, it's up to discussion; I am definitely not saying your answer is *wrong* per se.

Comment: @NominalAnimal: I did not pay enough attention to async-signal safe functions... Post edited

Answer (score 0):

First up, a quote from the C11 standard, emphasis mine:

> **7.14.1.1 The `signal` function**
>
> 5 If the signal occurs other than as the result of calling the `abort` or `raise` function, **the behaviour is undefined if [...] the signal handler calls any function in the standard library** other than the `abort` function, the `_Exit` function, the `quick_exit` function, or the `signal` function with the first argumentt equal to the signal number corresponding to the signal that caused the invocation of the handler.

This means calling `fflush` is **undefined behaviour**.

Looking at the functions you *may* call, `abort` and `_Exit` both leave the flushing of buffers implementation-defined, and `quick_exit` calls `_Exit`, so you are out of luck as far as far as the standard is concerned since I could not find the implementation's definition on their behaviour for Linux. (Surprise. Not.)

The only other "terminating" function, `exit`, *does* flush the buffers, and you may not call it from the handler in the first place.

So you have to look at Linux-specific functionality. The man page to `_exit` makes no statement on buffers. The `close` man page warns against closing file descriptors that may be in use by system calls from other threads, and states that "it is not common for a filesystem to flush the buffers when the stream is closed", meaning that it *could* happen (i.e. `close` not guaranteeing that unwritten buffer contents are actually discarded).

At this point, if I were you, I would ask myself "is this such a good idea after all"...

Comment: the requirement is this , i am not telling i need to use fpurge ... couldn't able to find anything about from this . i dont want to kill the process , i just dont want to display naything on the terminal .

Comment: @manimuthuma: So you want to catch the SIGINT and continue program execution, merely disabling terminal output? I would not worry about what is in the buffers, anyway. It is at maximum one line of output (since the terminal is interactive, i.e. output is line-buffered unless you did set it to fully-buffered yourself). And Ctrl-C is *user* input, i.e. not precisely timed anyways. So, set a `atomic_t` flag, `freopen()` stdout to `/dev/null` to disable *future* output at the next opportunity (since you may not call `freopen()` from the signal handler), and just ignore any buffered data.

Comment: Note that since Linux is tagged in the question, POSIX is also a standard to consider. And it has quite a bit to say about [signals](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html). Also, `signal()` is not recommended to be used, and [`sigaction()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) should be used instead.

Comment: Yes, just found `man 7 signal` myself. Neither `fflush()` nor `freopen()` are in the list of save functions. `close()`, however, is. (Doesn't say anything about the flushing of buffers, though.) I still think OP is barking up the wrong tree. We're talking about the race condition of the user pressing Ctrl-C *while there is some stdio output buffered*. I wouldn't worry too much about whether that line is printed or not. If this is a security issue, you have different problems (relying on the user to press Ctrl-C in time)...

Comment: @DevSolar: as `close` is at a lower level, it should have no effect on buffering of standard library `FILE*`.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: Well, there is buffering going on both above the fid level (`setvbuf()` et al.) and below it (as evidenced by the line from the `close` manpage about filesystems). And as sadly common, documentation really *specifying* what will happen is sparse.

Answer (score 0):

If you do `kill(getpid(), SIGKILL);` with in the signal handler (which is async-safe), you would get killed immediately by the OS (as you wanted to exit(0) anyway). Further output is not to be expected any more.

Only problem: you won't be able to clean up poperly, exit gracefully afterwards in the main thread. If you can afford that...

Comment: i dont want to kill the process

Comment: Hm, understand, then exit(0) was just for experimenting... OK, then no solution for you.